# One of the columns is not showing the miliseconds after I filter the data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter

I'm using `pandas 2.1.3` library, on `python 3.11`, to read an `.xlsx` file, that `.xlsx` file has 4 timestamp columns: `'FN_CTime', 'FN_ATime', 'FN_MTime', 'FN_RTime'`, all four using the same format in excel:
`dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss,000` to show `milliseconds`. If I print the data without do any filter, all these four columns shows the milliseconds of their values, but after I filter to show only the values that ends in `.000`, I mean, the ones that's have their milliseconds to zero, the only column that doesn't show the milliseconds its `FN_CTime`.

[image: 'FN_CTime' not showing miliseconds]

```
def function():
    pd.set_option("display.precision", 6)
    data = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col=[0], usecols=['HEADER_MFTREcordNumber', 'FN_ParentReferenceNo', 'FN_FileName', 'FilePath', 'HEADER_Flags', 'FN_CTime', 'FN_ATime', 'FN_MTime', 'FN_RTime'])

    #print(data)
    
    condition = data[['FN_CTime', 'FN_ATime', 'FN_MTime', 'FN_RTime']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.endswith(".000"))

    
    filtered_data = data[condition.any(axis=1)]
    print(filtered_data)
```

This is my function's code:

I read the file, use some columns cause I don't want to use all of them, just below I comment `print(data)`, if I print it there, `FN_CTime` show the milliseconds, but when I `print(filtered_data)`, `FN_CTime` is the only one that doesn't show the milliseconds, fun fact, if I remove `'FN_CTime'` from the condition, then neither `'FN_CTime'` or `'FN_ATime'` shows milliseconds, all in the `.xlsx` file is fine btw. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Check these columns dtypes: df.dtypes()

Comment: Can you explain a little more?